# undefined reference general errors

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to implement the functionality of a stack and I was given the main.cpp file and was left to write the other files, namely StackofNodes.hpp & .h. These depend on two other files Node.hpp & .h. When I try to build the program I get errors on the main.cpp file that was given to me. This are:

```
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `main':|
|6|undefined reference to `StackOfNodees<int>::StackOfNodees()'|
|12|undefined reference to `StackOfNodees<int>::push(int)'|
|17|undefined reference to `StackOfNodees<int>::size() const'|
|24|undefined reference to `StackOfNodees<int>::pop()'|
```

main.cpp

```
   #include <iostream> //std::cout std::cin
    #include "StackOfNodees.h" //StackOfNodes

    int main()
    {
        StackOfNodees<int> myStack; //Create an empty stack
        int sizeOfStack;    //int we'll use later to store the size of the stack

        //push some numbers onto the stack
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            myStack.push( i * 5 );
        }


        //Store the size of the stack before popping anything
        sizeOfStack = myStack.size();

        std::cout << "There are " << sizeOfStack << " items on the stack" << std::endl;

        //Think about why we don't use i<myStack.size()
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfStack; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Popping the top: " << myStack.pop() << std::endl;
        }

            /* while(!myStack.isEmpty()) is another valid way to pop all the contents of the stack */

    }
```

StackOfNodees.hpp

```
#ifndef STACKOFNODEES_HPP_INCLUDED
#define STACKOFNODEES_HPP_INCLUDED

StackOfNodees::StackOfNodees()
{
    m_top=nullptr;
    m_size=0;
}

bool StackOfNodees::isEmpty() const
{
    if (m_size==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int StackOfNodees::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

void StackOfNodees::push(int value)
{
    Node* Node1 = new Node;
    Node1 -> m_previous = m_top;
    m_top=Node1;
    Node1 -> m_value = value;
    ++m_size;
}

int StackOfNodees::pop()
{
    // initialize
    int returnval = 0;

    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        // fetch the value from the top one
        returnval = m_top -> m_value;

        Node* temp = m_top;

        //move m_top down to previous box.
        m_top = m_top -> m_previous;

        //delete the popped one
        delete temp;

        m_size--;
    }
    else
    {
        // you may want to throw an exception here for popping a empty stack
    }

    return returnval;
}




#endif // STACKOFNODEES_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    Node.setPrevious(nullptr);
    Node.setValue();
}

//initiation of getters
    template<typename T>
    T Node::getValue()
    {
        return m_value;
    }//end getValue

    template<typename int>
    int Node::getPrevious()
    {
        return m_previous;
    }//end getPrevious

//initiation of setters
    template<typename void>
    void Node::setValue(T value)
    {
        m_value =  value;
    }//end setValue

    template<typename void>
    void Node::setPrevious(Node<T>* previous)
    {
        Node<T>* previous = m_previous;
    }//end setPrevious
```

StackOfNodees.h

```
#ifndef STACKOFNODEES_H_INCLUDED
#define STACKOFNODEES_H_INCLUDED
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
class StackOfNodees
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_top;
    int m_size;

public:
    StackOfNodees();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push(T value);
    T pop();
};

#endif // STACKOFNODEES_H_INCLUDED
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're using a templated `StackOfNodes`, but you're defining a non-templated `StackOfNodes`.

Comment: You're not really using the file StackOfNodees.hpp at all.  (If you did, the compiler would complain about the problem a few other people have mentioned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have methods of template class StackOfNodees defined.
You need to have

```
template<typename T>
StackOfNodees<T>::StackOfNodees()
{
    m_top=nullptr;
    m_size=0;
}
```

Rather than

```
StackOfNodees::StackOfNodees()
{
    m_top=nullptr;
    m_size=0;
}
```

Change all definitions and move them into StackOfNodees.h file from .hpp. You do not need an extra .hpp file.

Example:

```
// File a.h
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A();
    // the rest of the class ....
};

template<typename T>
A<T>::A()
{
    // ...
}
```

file app.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
void main()
{
    A<int> a;
...
}
```

***An extra .hpp file makes code less readable*** as it breaks reading flow. If you are still required to split your code in that manner then you need to include .hpp into .h file with `#include "StackOfNodes.hpp"` instruction in the bottom of .h file (a rather unconventional approach).

Comment: I added my `StackOfNodees.h` to the original question. Does this change what your answer is? I'm not familiar with `templates` at all.

Comment: I've added `StackOfNodees.h` is that what you asked for?

Comment: Ok so I change what you said but the error remains 
`main.cpp|6|undefined reference to "StackOfNodees<int>::StackOfNodees()"|'

Comment: I wrote basically the same as you. I could add it to the original question if you'd like

Comment: Do you think this has something to do with the `#include "blahblah"`?

Comment: @rubito you won't get far into C++ without running into templates.  Very powerful but IMHO overused feature.

Comment: I've added all that I have. Also, the instructions tell us to use .hpp and .h file. The only .cpp is the `main.cpp`

Comment: @seand yeah I figured it's an useful concept since we are spending a good week on it. What happened is that I somehow managed to get in the advanced c++ programming class and now I'm struggling through it.

Comment: Note how your Node class is defined. If you have to use both .h and .hpp (not sure why to multiply files) then you need to include .hpp into .h file. In the bottom of StackOfNodees.h: `#include "StackOfNodees.hpp"`

Comment: Ok, so I added `#include "StackOfNodes.hpp"` to the bottom of StackOfNodees.h and it cleared up the errors with my main. And I think the errors that I'm now getting are due to not having templates for my methods defined. Either way thanks a lot @dmitri.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing a template class, you must provide definition of the template class in the same file where the declaration itself lies, so that the compiler can instantiate the actual class when compiling.

In this specific case, put the definitions in `StackOfNodees.hpp` back to the template class declaration in the file `StackOfNodees.h` after changing this `int` specific one to general type `T` one. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp) is a simple tutorial about the format of a template class.

Comment: C++ templates are like macros on performance enhancing drugs.  Similar to a macro, the compiler has to "see" all the text to a template.  Referencing in an external .o won't cut it.

Comment: @WiSaGaN It is not enough to do what you've suggested. `StackOfNodees.hpp` doesn't have definitions of the template class. It contains definitions of an unrelated non template class that happened to have very "similar" name.